# Inefficient transmission of protobuf-net serialized messages

Tags: wcf, performance, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, nettcpbinding

I have a `WCF` service hosted on Windows Server 2008/IIS exposing a `nettcpbinding` endpoint using the `DataContractSerializer`.  This service is consumed by a Windows Forms application, which is suffering from various performance issues.  In an effort to reduce the payload transferred from server-to-client over our corporate network, I decided to integrate the `protobuf-net` (version r580) serialization engine into some of my service's operations using the `ProtoBehavior` attribute.

Prior to integration of`protobuff-net`, the cumulative size of the serialized server responses was approximately 18 MB.  Afterwards, it was 1.6 MB, as verified with WCF trace logs on both client and server; unfortunately, this didn't result in decreased loading times in the client application.

After digging into it further, I found that the bytes received by the client over the network, pre-`protobuf` vs. post-`protobuf`, only differed by about 1MB, as reported by a network traffic tool.  How can this be?  How can payloads differing by almost 15 MB in their serialized form (comprising of several messages), only represent a 1 MB difference when transmitted over the network?  Could the resulting TCP stream be overly bloated if the underlying `protobuff` stream is assembled a certain way?

Additionally, I should note that the `protobuf-net` serialized payload of 1.6 MB is comprised of several response messages, one of which is approximately 1.25 MB by itself; could this be the issue?  Should I work on breaking that into smaller responses?  If so, what's the threshold?

I'd appreciate any input regarding this as it's been puzzling me for a couple of weeks now.  I've spent hours pouring through posts relating to `protobuf-net`, and while it's delivering on it's promise of providing a compact serialization format, I haven't been able to realize the benefits in practice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the nature of your API? is it lots of small messages? if so, is it possible that you're simply drowning in protocol overheads?

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the quick reply... the short answer is, it depends.

Comment: ...sorry, inadvertently hit 'Enter'.  The service operations that were modified to use protobuf-net were responsible for retrieving collections of reference data elements for binding to drop down lists, list boxes, etc...  These requests are usually batched/coordinated into one server request that will retrieve a collection of collections, which in some cases yields the 1.25 MB response (protobuf serialized) I mentioned in my original post.  In general, our client application is chatty; it isn't uncommon for certain areas to generate 10+ server requests.

Comment: @Marc - I was looking into your comment regarding protocol overheads; I'm assume you're referring to the overhead being added by `protobuf-net` during serialization?  Is there a strategy to avoid this overhead? I was under the impression that `protobuf-net` was appropriate for small and large object trees.  In any case, all of the responses in question contain repeated elements (i.e. collections), which were implemented using wrapper objects containing a List<T> property adorned with the `ProtoMember(1, DataFormat=DataFormat.Grouped)` attribute.

Comment: No, protocol overheads is the exact opposite of that: it is the fixed cost that you pay even for small messages, unrelated to the serializer - so, identity headers, session tokens, encryption / security info, soap verbosity, despatcher info, etc

Comment: Are you suggesting this overhead is the reason I'm not seeing any noticeable performance improvements? If this overhead is truly fixed, shouldn't I still be seeing improvements due to the reduced payload? My service utilizes transport -level security, is a single-context instance with concurrency enabled, and doesn't utilize sessions, reliable messaging, transaction flow, etc...

Comment: Additionally, there are areas in my client application that don't generate a large amount of server requests (e.g. 2-3), and the performance issues persist even though the response payload was dramatically reduced.  Ultimately, I'm trying to determine if it's possible to use `protobuf-net` in a such a way, that while technically correct, can lead to a serialized message being inefficiently loaded onto the transport layer or can in-itself contain overhead?

Comment: it is hard to be precise when I don't have the data, but *generalising*, yes if you had large numbers of small messages, then regardless of the serializer chose, the payload becomes an insignificant measure. The "1.25 by itself" certainly should be big enough to observe a difference, though. What you describe is unusual, and does not tally with my own usage observations, but: I lack any ability to investigate.

Comment: Are there any additional pieces of data of could provide to help clarify?

Comment: Here are some more specifics.  Prior to integration of `protobuf-net`, my service was returning serialized responses totaling 18MB with the over-the-wire bytes received by the application at 2,200,000 bytes (~2MB).  After integration of 'protobuf-net`, the service was returning serialized responses totaling 1.6MB with the over-the-wire bytes received by the application at 1,200,000 bytes (~1.2MB).  As you can see, there was an 89% reduction in serialized message size, but only a 55% reduction in the payload transmitted over-the-wire.

Comment: intriguing; I can only conclude NDCS is making long work of serializing a standard byte[]. How much can you change? have you tried using a basic-http-binding with MTOM enabled? that usually works really well with pb-net data.

Comment: Are you referring to the NetDataContractSerializer? Is that what's being used under the hood?  At one point I did try to use basic http w/MTOM; it didn't seem to make a noticeable difference, although I didn't record the exact numbers.

Comment: sorry, I mis-spoke; I meant the WCF packaging, i.e. how it makes the message *including* payload, but all the other overheads too.

Comment: using basic http w/MTOM yielded an over-the-wire payload of 1,326,000 bytes.  Can this scenario have anything to do with the format of the pb-net serialized message (more from the perspective of my usage, incorrect or otherwise)?

Comment: frankly, it sounds to me like WCF is applying gzip or similar, so: all bets would be off. Is this using encryption, for example? But hey: it is smaller!